# How to resolve "nptl-signals.h : no such file or directory"

Tags: gdb

I have been trying to analyze a core, but unable to receive the
complete backtrace due to following error :

```
#######################################
#0  0x0088ad6c in __libc_signal_restore_set (set=0xf48f2a78) at
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/nptl-signals.h:79
79 ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/nptl-signals.h: No such file or directory.
#######################################
```

Following is the (incomplete) backtrace :

```
#######################################
[Current thread is 1 (LWP 7491)]
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0088ad6c in __libc_signal_restore_set (set=0xf48f2a78) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/nptl-signals.h:79
#1  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:48
#2  0x0088cb78 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#3  <frame with modified names> 0x049b3a54 in func_1 (ffp=<optimized out>, base_name=<optimized out>, max_size=<optimized out>, file_type=<optimized out>)
    at a/b/c/d/e:58
#4  0x00000270 in ?? ()
(gdb)
#######################################
```

Since GDB is able to find raise.c, I did a full base-machine search
for it, via :

```
#######################################
find / -name raise.c 2> /dev/null
#######################################
```

but could not find raise.c either on the base-machine filesystem.

So, following are my queries :

1. Where are raise.c, nptl-signals.h etc. supposed to reside?
2. How can we bring back the missing nptl-signals.h file?

Answer (score 0):

> Where are raise.c, nptl-signals.h etc. supposed to reside?

They are part of GLIBC. You can find the sources [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git).

> How can we bring back the missing nptl-signals.h file?

Download the GLIBC source package for your distribution.

---

That said, your questions and the sources are *irrelevant* to your problem, which is that `func_1` called [abort()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/abort.3.html) on line 58 of `a/b/c/d/e`.

Your problem is *not* with `nptl-signals.h` -- it's with `func_1`.